# java method which can be changed

Tags: java, methods, overriding

I'm a little unclear on how to make this method. it has to make a method called setCapacity that later can override. I have to "Modify the class Vehicle, the base class, to include a method called setCapacity which
allows the engine capacity to be changed"

```
class Vehicle {
      void setCapactiy1 () {
         int setCapactity == 0;
      }
   }      
   int capacity;
   String make;

   Vehicle(int theCapacity, String theMake) {
      capacity = theCapacity;
      make = theMake;
   }

   void print() {
      System.out.println("Vehicle Info:");
      System.out.println("  capacity = " + capacity + "cc" );
      System.out.println("  make = " + make );
   }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
   public String type;
   public String model;

   public Car(int theCapacity, String theMake, String theType, String theModel) {
      super(theCapacity, theMake);
      type = theType;
      model = theModel;
   }

   @Override
   public void print() {
      super.print();
      System.out.println("  type = " + type);
      System.out.println("  model = " + model);
   }

   @Override

}

class Task2 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Car car1 = new Car(1200,"Holden","sedan","Barina");
      Car car2 = new Car(1500,"Mazda","sedan","323");
      car1.print();
      car2.print();
   }
}
```

Comment: java setter methods accept an argument that is the new value

Comment: Over the last couple of days you have left a trail of these questions, without any acceptance of answers

Comment: you did not pass the capacity in your `setCapacity` method arguments. it should be like : `setCapacity(int capacity)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a basic setter... It should go like

```
public void setCapacity(int newCapacity) {
    this.capacity = newCapacity;
}
```